# Connecting to my SMTP server

Tags: smtp

I have a few questions, I just installed SMTP on my Ubuntu server, and I want to know how to connect to it from a different machine... I'm not really clear.

I tried:

```
telnet my.servers.ip.address 25
```

I think it's running on port 25, but I don't know where to find out, its not in the conf file anywhere.

Additionally do I need it to be a FDQN? or can I just access my mail server via it's IP address? I know that the service works on the machine because I'm able to

```
echo test | mail -s "test" me@gmail.com
```

Any help debugging or understanding this would be helpful, thanks guys!

Comment: "installed"? Did you configure it?

Comment: I did, but I'm not really 100% sure what the right configuration is, lots of the tutorials suggest setting it up as a "Satellite", but I'm just not sure what is the common, setup or rather the preferred one.

Comment: What smtp server - postfix?

Comment: Yah I'm using postfix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the netstat command to see which services are listening on what ports.

```
   netstat -ntlp
```

Make sure the mail server is listening on more than just the loopback interface. It most likely isn't by default, for security reasons.